# Is there any difference between delete x and delete(x)?

Tags: c++

In C++ is there any difference between the following commands:

```
delete x;
delete(x);
```

Comment: `x` and `(x)` in general have very few contexts where they differ.

Comment: The only difference is that if you use the latter, whoever reads your code will probably end on this exact page.

Comment: It makes a difference when `x` is `#define x (char*)0) ; (0` :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the same as the difference between:

```
i = i + 1;
i = i + (1);
```

i.e. none. `delete` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: `sizeof` is also an operator. And yet the parentheses make a difference. (Arguably, my point is pedantic because the expression can be parenthesized so `sizeof 4` and `sizeof(4)` are both valid. But it's still misleading.)

Answer (score 17):

No, there's absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is only if the `x` is expanded by a pre-compiler, in which case the semantics of the `(x)` will cause an evaluation of the `x` expression before calling an `operator delete` on the result of that evaluation.